# How is MESSAGE_ID set in journalctl?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I notice some programs have a `MESSAGE_ID` associated with a particular log line, but others don't.

For example, NetworkManager doesn't have `MESSAGE_ID` on my machine.

```
journalctl -o json --identifier NetworkManager | tail -n 1 | jq --sort-keys
```

But if you check systemd, you'll see it sometimes.

```
journalctl -o json --identifier systemd | jq --sort-keys | less
```

Why is that? Is there a way to turn this feature on? Maybe in a unit file or something?

I did find this, but it only describes the field. It doesn't talk about enabling it.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that MESSAGE_ID can be set when using logger with --journald if you use it to send messages to journals. Digging in various journals on different systems I see a lot of identical MESSAGE_ID's. I have not found out yet what a unique MESSAGE_ID signifies, so I am asking my own question.